# The $\lambda^+$-Baire property for the case $\mathrm{cf}(\lambda)=\omega$

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

A topological space is called $\lambda$-Baire if the intersection less then $\lambda$ open dense sets is dense. For reference, [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/152503) are some  facts and examples of $\lambda$-Baire spaces where $\lambda$ is not the successor of a singular cardinal.

I'm interested in examples of $\lambda^+$-Baire spaces, that are not $\lambda^{++}$-Baire, where $\lambda$ is a singular cardinal of co-finality $\omega$. One such space is $\lambda^+$ with the co-finite topology. Are there examples of such spaces, which also satisfy the Hausdorff property?